# asp.net: UI design best practice?

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, user-input

In my asp.net application I have a form where a user can pick a few skills (there are over 40) and per skill can define his skill level (value from 1-10).

My initial idea was to show 1 combobox with a slider next to it.
Everytime the user picks a skill a new combobox with all the skills + slider appears underneath it and the picked skill combobox + slider gets a delete button next to it, in case they want to delete the previous selected skill.

At first this seemed like a good idea, but now that I'm building it it looks kinda weird and not that intuitive.

How would you guys implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combo box for multiple selections with additional input is not a good idea. Can you list the skills ( I know 40 is quite a few, but it depends on the aplication usage )? Having a skill, with a checkbox ( that can be unchecked ) and a slider of level appearing to the side would be my initial thought.

Of course, UI design is very specific to a particular application and user base. Different applications have different requirements.

ETA - based on comments, the other option is to split the task into two pieces ( TBH, that would probably be a better and more efficient solution to this task. That is my PhD study area, so I might know what I am talking about ). Can you have one page to select the list of skills, and another to list the selected ones, with sliders on ( and "remove" options too ). From a useability perspective, I would think this might be easier.

Comment: Very similar to the CyberCoders skill assessment page.

Comment: I see what you mean, the problem is also that the list of 40 can grow in the future. I think I'm gonna use 1 comebox with an add button next to it. On clicking add the name appears underneath it with a skilllevel slider and a delete option. Thanks for the answer though. Up till 20 this would be perfect for my application, but 40+ would look really messy and would confuse users I think.

Comment: I didn't notice your edit while i was editing my comment. Sometimes I think too much in database tables logic when designing UI. I try to cram every property and important 1-* relation into one form. Maybe creating a more wizard approach is a better idea. This splitting idea I like, I'm gonna check the needed user information and reorganise my registration form.